# Lithium: Custom data source results in call to undefined method `configureClass()`

Tags: model, customization, lithium

I'm trying to create a data source to work with CSV's.
I'm following [this example](http://lithify.me/docs/manual/working-with-data/creating-data-sources.wiki)

connections.php:

```
Connections::add('csv', [
        'type' => 'file',
        'adapter' => 'Csv',
    ]
);
```

app/extensions/adapter/data/source/file/Csv.php

```
namespace app\extensions\adapter\data\source\file;

use lithium\core\Libraries;

class Csv extends \app\extensions\adapter\data\source\File {

    public function __construct(array $config = []) {
        $defaults = [
            'delimiter' => ',',
            'enclosure' => '\"',
            'escape' => '\\',
            'path' => Libraries::get(true, 'resources') . '/file/csv',
        ];
        $config += $defaults;
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    public function read($query, array $options = array()) {
        print_r($query);
        die();
    }
}
```

app/extensions/adapter/data/source/File.php

```
<?php

namespace app\extensions\adapter\data\source;

use lithium\core\Libraries;

class File extends \lithium\core\Object {
    public function __construct(array $config = array()) {
        $defaults = array(
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
            'path' => Libraries::get(true, 'resources') . '/file'
        );
        parent::__construct($config + $defaults);
    }
}

?>
```

app/models/Importers.php

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

class Importers extends \lithium\data\Model {
    protected $_meta = [ 
        'connection' => 'csv',
    ];
}
?>
```

Whenever I call `Importers::find('all');` from a controller, I get the error:

`Fatal error: Call to undefined method app\extensions\adapter\data\source\file\Csv::configureClass() in ...`

If I do define `configureClass()`, I get another error stating `enable()` is not defined.
Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it appears that `File` must extend the abstract class `\lithium\data\Source` which, in turn, extends `\lithium\core\Object`.

Therefore, `app/extensions/adapter/data/source/File.php` will look like this:

```
class File extends \lithium\data\Source {
```

These are the comments for Source.php:

```
/**
 * This is the base class for Lithium's data abstraction layer.
 *
 * In addition to utility methods and standardized properties, it defines the implementation tasks
 * for all Lithium classes that work with external data, such as connections to remote resources
 * (`connect()` and `disconnect()`), introspecting available data objects (`sources()` and
 * `describe()`), and a standard read/write interface (`create()`, `read()`, `update()` and
 * `delete()`).
 *
 * Subclasses may implement any other non-standard functionality, but the above methods define the
 * requirements for interacting with `Model` objects, and other classes within `lithium\data`.
 */
```

Hope that helps someone (if I'm not wrong :)).
I love this framework!